# record is inserted but id is not generating using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

When i am inserting record in a table using hibernate than it is giving exception like -:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: The database returned no natively generated identity value
at org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper.getGeneratedIdentity(IdentifierGeneratorHelper.java:90)
at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:100)
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
```

my table structure is, here i used generation type "auto" -:

```
 @Entity
@Table(name="OBJECTIVE")
public class Objective implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long objectiveID;
    private String objectiveName;
    private String objectiveDescription;
    private int orderValue;
    private int yearValue;
    private Goal goal;
    private Frequency frequency;
    private Objective  objective;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="OBJECTIVE_ID")
    public Long getObjectiveID() {
        return objectiveID;
    }
    public void setObjectiveID(Long objectiveID) {
        this.objectiveID = objectiveID;
    }

    @Column(name="OBJECTIVE_NAME")
    public String getObjectiveName() {
        return objectiveName;
    }

    public void setObjectiveName(String objectiveName) {
        this.objectiveName = objectiveName;
    }

    @Column(name="OBJECTIVE_DESCRIPTION")
    public String getObjectiveDescription() {
        return objectiveDescription;
    }
    public void setObjectiveDescription(String objectiveDescription) {
        this.objectiveDescription = objectiveDescription;
    }

    @Column(name="ORDER_VALUE")
    public int getOrderValue() {
        return orderValue;
    }
    public void setOrderValue(int orderValue) {
        this.orderValue = orderValue;
    }

    @Column(name="YEAR_VALUE")
    public int getYearValue() {
        return yearValue;
    }
    public void setYearValue(int yearValue) {
        this.yearValue = yearValue;
    }


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="GOAL_ID")
    public Goal getGoal() {
        return goal;
    }
    public void setGoal(Goal goal) {
        this.goal = goal;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="FREQUENCY_ID")
    public Frequency getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }
    public void setFrequency(Frequency frequency) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="OBJECTIVE_PARENT_ID")
    public Objective getObjective() {
        return objective;
    }
    public void setObjective(Objective objective) {
        this.objective = objective;
    }
}
```

any suggetion will be helpful, same thing with other table is working.

Comment: What database are you using?  What generation strategy is the other table using?

Comment: mysql and same generation strategy which i used here....

Answer (score 0):

Check your table syntax in MySQL.

You have to give auto increment while creating the statement. For instance, take a look into this table in which I used auto increment:

```
create table customers(cid int(10) auto_increment, cname varchar(15), email varchar(30), phone int (10), city varchar(10), bal double(10,5), primary key(cid));
```